# Unterschied: "für sich lesen" vs "still lesen"?

Tags: meaning, difference

Da ich im Duden das Wort "still lesen" nicht finden konnte, habe ich einige Fragen dazu...Ist das dasselbe wie "für sich lesen"? Ist das ähnlich dem "leise lesen", oder muss man dabei ganz stumm (Mund zu) sein? Gibt es Unterschiede zw "still lesen" und "für sich lesen"? In der Bedeutung? In der Benutzung?

Answer (score 3):

"Stilllesen" gibt es als Wort nicht. "Still" ist ein Adjektiv, das hier als Adverb mit "lesen" benutzt wird, es bedeutet einfach "leise", "geräuschlos" oder "ohne etwas zu sagen". "Still lesen" bedeutet also lesen ohne etwas zu sagen oder Geräusche zu machen.

Zum Beispiel kann in der Schule der Lehrer die Klasse auffordern, einen Text "still zu lesen", das heißt, jeder und jede soll den Text lesen, ohne dass man sich mit anderen unterhält.

"Für sich lesen" dagegen bedeutet alleine lesen, also nicht mit einer anderen Person zusammen. Das heißt, die Bedeutung von "für sich lesen" ist eigentlich  anders als die von "still lesen", wobei in der Praxis, zumindest in der Schule, vermutlich ungefähr das gleiche gemeint ist.

Comment: Wenn Du noch einen Satz ergänzt, kriegst Du auch mein Upvote: Du hast die eigentliche Frage ob "still lesen" und "für sich lesen" dasselbe sind nicht beantwortet...

Comment: @Thorsten Link: ok, ich habe das noch ein bisschen klarer abgesetzt.

Comment: Ich kenne *still lesen* nur als Gegensatz zu *laut lesen* / *vorlesen*, was für Kinder, die Lesen lernen, schwieriger ist.